# Blender 2.93 for Ubuntu 18.04 ARM64?

Tags: gpu

I got myself a Nvidia Jetson Nano (actually I got a compute cluster of 5 [picocluster]) which comes with Ubuntu 18.04

The blender on Ubuntu 18.04 is pretty old.

I was hoping to test out the newer GPU capable renderer that comes with Blender 2.93

Short of have to build Blender from source, is there any pre-compiled Blender 2.93 that works with Ubuntu 18.04 ARM64

Cheers

Comment: Try asking [HERE](https://devtalk.blender.org/)